# Why can't I restrict a NumericStepper to include the negative sign?

Tags: apache-flex

I want to restrict my NumericStepper so that you can't type invalid characters into it (like a comma).  I'm trying this, and it works:

```
<s:initialize>
    stepper.textDisplay.restrict = "0-9 \- .";
</s:initialize>

<s:NumericStepper id="stepper" />
```

Except the negative sign can't be typed anymore, even though I specify it.

If I do it directly on a TextInput, it works:

```
<s:TextInput restrict="0-9 \- ." minimum="-10" />
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: is the `minimum` property set to a negative number?

Comment: In the example I gave, the default is zero but it doesn't matter.  Either way, it fails.  I updated the example to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is Numeric Stepper Allows only the Three Special Characters **.,-** 
the text display in the numeric stepper is restricted to

```
textDisplay.restrict = "0-9\\-\\.\\,";
```

Since if you want to restrict the **-,.** you can use like this

```
<s:initialize>
    stepper.textDisplay.restrict = "0-9";
</s:initialize>

<s:NumericStepper id="stepper" />
```

this is quite enough and worked for me, the same can be used for the `s:TextInput`. The Format you used is not correct, the accepted backslash sequences are `\-, \^ or \\` while using the ActionScript a double backslash must be used.

For More Information refer the Document [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/text/TLFTextField.html#restrict).

Comment: Nice.  Thanks.  The restriction I want is `stepper.textDisplay.restrict = "0-9\\-\\."`.  Thanks for the good catch on the syntax gaffe.